# DeprecationWarning process.EventEmitter is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos, deprecation-warning

Already applied require('events') but still the warning is keep showing, what is that i am doing wrong here? Why `process.EventEmitter` is keep showing up even its not used?

**Node v6.7.0 it works, but v6.9.1 this is happening on CentOS 7.2**

```
var pro = require('events');
var port = parseInt(config.server.port, 10);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port); // This line is causing it???
```

**Output Warning:**

```
dev environment detected
   info  - socket.io started
(node:32708) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
```

**EDIT:**

I used `$ npm install`
where package.json had following:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "description": "TEST",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "getconfig": "0.3.0",
    "node-uuid": "1.2.0",
    "socket.io": "0.9.16",
    "yetify": "0.0.1"
  },
  "main": "test.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "0.9.16",
    "precommit-hook": "0.3.10",
    "tape": "^2.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be using and old version of socket.io because in your code you don't use process.EventEmitter directly. If this program that you posted shows the warning then this is what could be the problem.

On my system the same program doesn't cause the problem - node 7.0.0 and socket.io 1.5.1 - but maybe you didn't include all of your code in your example (e.g. the `config.server.port` is not defined so you seem to have removed some portions of your code that may be relevant here).

You can see the version that you're using in:

```
node_modules/socket.io/package.json
```

See your own `package.json` and search for a line like:

```
"socket.io": "^1.4.8"
```

(like [this line](https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io/blob/master/package.json#L37) in one of my projects on GitHub) to see what version is installed with `npm install` and update the version if it's outdated. It's also possible that you have the `socket.io` module installed globally.

You can use [David](https://david-dm.org/) to let you know that you have outdated dependencies.

You can use [Greenkeeper](https://greenkeeper.io/) to help you keep your dependencies up to date.

(It's also good to add [Snyk](https://snyk.io/) to let you know about vulnerabilities in your dependencies.)

#### Update

You posted your package.json and indeed you use an old version of socket.io:

```
"socket.io": "0.9.16",
```

so this exact version is installed when you run `npm install`. The current version is 1.5.1 - see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

You can change the version and rerun `npm install`. If the code is exactly the same as posted then you shouldn't need to change your code. If there is more code then see http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/ for things that may need to be changed.

If you use CI tests, David and Greenkeeper, as I suggest above, then all of that (updating the version, testing if it still works etc.) would basically be done for you automatically.

If you use Snyk, as I also suggest above, then you'll know the version of socket.io that you're using has high-severity vulnerabilities, including Denial of Service and Remote Memory Exposure - that you now have in your code. See:

- https://snyk.io/test/npm/socket.io/0.9.15 [image: Known Vulnerabilities]
- https://snyk.io/test/npm/socket.io/1.5.1 [image: Known Vulnerabilities]

So as you can see, updating the socket.io dependency is important for more serious reasons than just the deprecation warning.

Comment: Your socket.io version is: `"socket.io": "0.9.16",` - the current version is 1.5.1 - see https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io You can change the version and rerun `npm install`. If the code is exactly the same as posted then you shouldn't need to change your code. If there is more code then see http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/ for things that may need to be changed.

Comment: @YumYumYum See [this gist that I wrote](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) with explanation on how you can install Node 6.7.0 on Linux. I explained how to install from binaries or from source. You should be able to install the correct version with no problems. The only tricky part is get the paths right. I explained everything in the gist, it's too long for a comment.

Comment: GURU!!! Outstanding mind-blowing doc. its working now i have parallel Old NodeJS and New on CentOS 7.2 and its working perfectly. Please keep this excellent mind blowing documentation of yours: https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

Comment: @YumYumYum Thanks. :) I will never remove this documentation. :)

Comment: @YumYumYum If you have /opt/node-6.7.0/bin/node then you should also have /opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm - running `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm install forever -g` should install forever using the new node and npm **but** it may install it not where you want if you installed the binary package. Run `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm config get prefix` and if it's not `/opt/node-6.7.0` but some other then you may need to edit the first line of /opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm program and change `#!/usr/bin/env node` to `#!/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/node` **or** run npm as `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/node /opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm`

Comment: @YumYumYum **or** you can run `export PATH="/opt/node-6.7.0/bin:$PATH"` in your terminal and then run npm install etc. The thing is that to install forever or other modules in the correct place then both npm and node should be run from the new version of node. To test your PATH you can run `which node` and `which npm` and also `npm config get prefix`. Correctly installing forever for new version of node and npm should install it in `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/forever` but here also may be a problem with `#!/usr/bin/env node` in its first line. You can change it or set PATH before running forever.

Comment: Is it not better. 1) yum remove nodejs (so that it removes v6.9.0)  2) use your method to compile from node 6.7.0 and 6.9.0 binary as per your documentation? 3) then manually use the forever as per your comments? cause when i did `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/npm install forever -g` it was use /usr/local/bin/forever instead of expected `/opt/node-6.7.0/bin/forever`